# Cannot set log4j logger level with Tomcat 6

Tags: log4j, tomcat6

I am using `log4j-1.2.16.jar` with Tomcat 6. The log4j config is handled with a `log4j.xml` file in the `WEB-INF\classes` directory. I turned log4j debug on. When it process a level element for a logger I get output like:

```
log4j: Level value for root is  [WARNING].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
```

Therefore all debug messages are logged when not wanted.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Level should be `WARN` not `WARNING`.

(It would be nice if `log4j.debug` gave an invalid level message.)